# Is there any $\alpha$ for which $e^{\alpha}$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, integers

Is there any $\alpha$ which gives  $e^{\alpha}$ an integer.

$\alpha=0$ is the trivial one.

But is there any other than $0$?

Comment: $\alpha = \log n$ with $n\in\ \mathbb{Z}$ works.

Comment: What conditions are there on $\alpha$? for example, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ set $\alpha = \ln x$

Comment: $\alpha = \ln(N)$, where $N$ is an integer

Comment: @pregunton: I assume you mean $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n>0$.

Comment: @WillR Negative integers also work if you allow $\alpha$ to be complex, and even $n=0$ if you allow $\alpha$ to be $-\infty$ (as in the extended reals). The question doesn't specify a particular condition on $\alpha$, so I gave the most general answer.

Comment: @pregunton: How are you defining $\log{n}$ if $n$ is negative? Or are you saying it doesn't matter in this context (presumably because $\exp{\log{n}}$ would be the same no matter what definition you choose)?

Comment: @WillR In this case it doesn't matter, as you say. Any branch of the complex logarithm works, or the complex logarithm itself as a multivalued function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very common example is the value a=ipi

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course. Any number of the form $\ln(n)$ with $n$ whole.

$e^x$ is a continuous map from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$ so it is immediately necessary that for any integer you choose, there is some $x$ where $e^x$=it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $\ln(n)$ where $n$ is any positive integer.
You see $\ln$ is the natural logarithm and is the inverse of $\exp$.